# How would I write to memory?

Tags: c, testing, memory, embedded, ram

I am trying to write a simple test for RAM to check basic integrity of the memory on board an embedded device. This is what I want to be able to do:

Essentially write out certain patterns: "10101010101010" to a block of memory then write "01010101010" then re-write the first one and test to see if the pattern was written correctly.

I am trying to write this program in C. I was wondering how I would go about writing this pattern. I want to be able to flip certain bits  within the RAM memory cells on and off.

Would I just get allocate a block of memory and then write do something like

```
uint32 pattern = 0xaaaaaaaa;
uint32 * mem_loc = malloc some memory;
int i = 0;
int offset = 1; 
uint32 * location = &mem_loc;

while ((&mem_loc)++ && (!i))  {
   &mem_loc = pattern;
   if (!(&(mem_loc+offet))) { 
      mem_loc = location;
      pattern = 0x55555555;
      i++;
   }
}

//Check to see if values written are consistent
```

Would the code above work?? Will writing out the hex patterns to memory turn the bits on in the pattern?

I know the code above is horribly mangled but I just want to get an idea if doing something like that with the correct logic will achieve the desired result.

Thanks

Comment: Google "walking ones" and "walking zeroes" memory testing algorithms

Comment: The general idea you've outlined should work. The code you have isn't even close though. Just for example, I'm not sure what `!int` is even supposed to mean, but I'm pretty sure no properly functioning compiler will accept it.

Comment: Not enough information - does your processor have cache? How about your OS - does it have a virtual memory system?  Do you care what addresses you write to?  Besides that, your code example doesn't make sense.  What's `!int`?  The use of `malloc()` seems to indicate that your code is running from RAM - doesn't that indicate that its "basic integrity" is ok?

Comment: You code looks very strange... Why use &mem_loc ? It's a constant (mem_loc address), it will never change, it's not like mem_lot VALUE. And when you whant to write into memory, you have to use *mem_loc=pattern instead. (!int) is also wrong.

Comment: woops sorry the int should have been an i.

Comment: And you will never be able to access all the memory like this, from a malloc. There are vast areas of memory you will never check (not even talking about virtual memory)

Comment: This actually depends much on the embedded platform and whether or not it has cache and an MMU, and if the OS allows flat access to all of memory etc... Basically, you usually need to hand-code assembler for it. The good news is that the assembly code is very, very small so you can usually learn enough to do it pretty fast. And it can be inlined into your C if you really need to for some reason. And C calling conventions are pretty standard unlike C++ so even that part is easy, you can implement it as a function.

Comment: Can we get some more details about your platform? How is the RAM you want to test connected to the processor? If you're coding on the 'bare metal' on something like an AVR you can usually just look up the memory map in the processor manual and start writing to the areas you wish to test.

Comment: @OrgnlDave, I wouldn't say you usually need assembly.  Our system has a complete ram test written in plain 'c'.  The tricky parts are about ensuring you don't clobber the memory the test code is using - but that can be managed by controlling the memory segments your code uses, and that can be done at complile/link time.

Comment: @AShelly I'm pretty sure that if his toolchain already included a memory test he wouldn't need one. With that said, accessing hardware resources like an MMU from C is without assembly *requires* an external library that interfaces with the underlying hardware and if the C program included isn't using one, it's doing it wrong.

Comment: I was unclear, sorry: I meant "for our embedded system, we have written a complete RAM test in plain C".   Whether or not assembly is required probably depends a lot on the exact hardware.  All I can say is that I have personal experience with more than one embedded processors which allow direct access to all the memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a chicken and egg problem.  In order to get enough code running to do mallocs or even use C code, you already have working memory.

You need to define your problem.  For example is this design verification or production testing?  Are you testing the memory chip itself or the board.  Normally you will buy working/tested chips (memory) or memory chips that have some vendor defined quality.  And your testing is often production testing, the manufacturing solder points.  The data lines, the address lines, the control lines.

The chicken and egg problem is you want to run software on the embedded processor which requires code that runs somewhere, and that implies memory (could just be flash and not need any or minimal).  the ideal situation is to either run completely out of rom, using processor resources only or internal chip resources only and no exteral ram so the external ram can be completely tested.  Every address line, etc.  Otherwise you need to come up with a scheme or declare chunks of memory to not be tested.

Or take a multi stage approach, the rom boot code can do a quick check of a small part of ram without using it to run.  Then copy the main test program to that small chunk of ram and run within it.  Then do the main memory tests with more code flexibility.  Can use C instead of assembler for example.  You might for example pre-test, super simple test, 25% of the ram, then copy the test there, test the other 75%, then move the program to another 25% in the ram space and do the heavy test on the first 25% that didnt get a full test.

Types of test, you need to understand the failures, you may want to test solder joints in particular and pcboard traces.  So you can have open connections so you want to make each pin a one and a zero, also you can have shorts, which the one and zero covers, and you might have "friendly bits" where neighboring pins might have a short to each other so you want to have each pair of signals be different from each other.

Often folks will do tests like all ones, all zeros, 5s, As.  Then checkerboard tests where one memory location has say 5s and the next has As.  for address line testing you need to use non-powers of two, or even better every memory location in memory has a different value, for example 32 bit words each getting their own address.

As a quick test I cover most of that in a couple of tests, if you use a pseudo randomizer, something repeatable like an lfsr, one pass to fill all of memory using the randomizer, re-seed, go back through and check.  then go through again and fill with inverted values, re-seed and verify inverted values.  you get address bits, each data line but not all neighbors are checked.  re-seeding and starting all of this over moving the random pattern around can cover that.  sometimes just using the random test as the address test and the traditional ones zeros fives As, 3s, Cs, 6s, 9s, etc.

as far as your pointer to memory under test you dont just malloc you need to know the physical address and deal with the translation if any so that if/when there is a problem you are communicating in physical addresses.  Also you know and control how much of the memory.  Normally I will write processor based tests in C, but wont use any C library calls (like malloc or printf or anything like that).

Comment: Thank you! However at this point the device is presenting with enough errors that sometimes writing a pattern to a "particular" spot and reading it back is getting inconsistant results.

Answer (score 2):

Echoing @Martin's answer:  you don't want to be using standard library calls to provide the memory to test.

Your embedded toolchain should be able to produce a memory map of your application.
You need to identify the memory segments you want to test, and extract their starting address from the map file.

The test loop could look something like:

```
 const int* AddressToTest = MEM_SEGMENT;
 const int* SegLength     = SEGMENT_LENGTH;
 volatile int* mem;
 for (mem = AddressToTest; mem < AddressToTest + SegLength; mem++)
 {
    *mem = PATTERN;
    if (*mem != PATTERN) {report("Read-Write Failure at %x",mem);}
 }
 //-or- you could separate the write and verify into 2 separate loops.
```

The big gotcha here is that you can't test the segment you are running from, so you need to plan carefully.  The embedded tools should have some sort of linker options file (and/or complier #pragmas) which control which code uses which memory.  So you'll need to set up your test code to run in a separate place than the memory under test.

Comment: I think a `volatile` is due here.

Comment: good point, added.    Also, see http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/Memory-Test-Suite-C for a good explanation of what kind of memory faults you should be testing for.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use `new` ?
If you are trying to test specific areas of the embedded system's memory don't you want to set  that address directly rather than relying on whatever `new` gives you?

If this *embedded* system is really linux or Windows embedded or some other complex OS then it's possibly more complex you may have memory address spaces for different process, caches, optimistic allocation to consider.